# SFML не распознает ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, macos, qtcreator, sfml

Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой SFML. Хочу узнать была ли клавиша нажата:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
```

Но вместо "A" в консоли выводит: we got a keyboard without any keys (1).

Я использую:

1. SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang
2. Qt creator(clang)
3. macOS Catalina 10.15.2

P.S. В разделе "Системные настройки" -> "Защита и безопасность" -> "Мониторинг ввода" не появляется никаких запросов на разрешение использования ввода с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы решить эту проблему нужно в разделе "Системные настройки" -> "Защита и безопасность" -> "Мониторинг ввода" самостоятельно найти и разрешить программе "Терминал" мониторинг клавиатуры.